# Why doesn't this XML disable my joomla radio button?

Tags: joomla

```
<field name="name" type="radio"
class="btn-group"
label="label"
description="description"   
default="0"
disabled = "true"         
filter="raw">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</field>
```

How are you disable radio button with xml ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that the disabled feature only works on option level, not for the whole field.
So you would need to set it like this:

```
<field name="name" type="radio"
    class="btn-group"
    label="label"
    description="description"   
    default="0"
    filter="raw">
    <option value="0" disabled="true">No</option>
    <option value="1" disabled="true">Yes</option>
</field>
```

However it doesn't work well together with the `btn-group` class. This is probably a Bootstrap bug.